# How to remove "/up" in accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 login_buttons_dropdown: forbidClientAccountCreation

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using the accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 package and login_buttons_dropdown. I want to get rid of the "/up" from "sign in/up". On the client side if I set forbidClientAccountCreation to true this solves my problem, but an error displays in the console:

**Accounts.config was called on the client but not on the server; some configuration options may not take effect.**

From my understanding forbidClientAccountCreation will only work if it is set to true on both the client and server. If I set forbidClientAccountCreation to true on the client and false on the server, what happens? Right now it solves my problem, I'm just wondering if I'm missing anything.

Answer (score 1):

I was having exactly the same issue. I was able to solve it by calling the following code on the client:

```
Accounts.config({
    forbidClientAccountCreation : true
});
```

I am also using german localization, so my entire config.js looks like this:

```
accountsUIBootstrap3.setLanguage("de");

Accounts.config({
    forbidClientAccountCreation : true
});
```